# Angular: Async process not triggering changeDetection only in >= Chrome 64

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection, zonejs

I'm monitoring the size of an element in angular using `ResizeObserver`

```
 observer = new window.ResizeObserver(entries => {
     ...
     someComponent.width = width;
 });
 observer.observe(target);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resize-observer?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

When you run the code in safary, firefox or chrome 63 it works just fine

[image]

So, in chrome 64 ([can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) -> native support) it doesn't work any more and it looks like this:

[image]

Somehow chrome doesn't do changeDetection for triggers from `ResizeObserver`

Any suggestion what might be the reason for this strange behaviour?

UPDATE: I'v updated my post based on the discussion below

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Chrome? `w` changes value and the yellow box changes size. What else should be expected to happen?

Comment: In my case the value changes once in a while (probably when angular does changeDetection), but it should change constantly

Comment: It does change constantly for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: You're right. It does work in safari and Firefox, but in Chrome it does not. I tested chrome 64 and 66

Comment: I'm on version 63 on Chrome. Updating and trying again.

Comment: Yes you are right. On version 64 it does not update correctly. That's not good.

Comment: That explains why I have seen my code working some time ago :) Most likely, I guess, this has something todo with ZoneJs, right?

Comment: I've updated the question a bit based on our findings, thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried manually triggering change detection in that callback?

Comment: I just updated the stackblitz, and yes if I do that it works. I could move the manual changeDetection into the ResizeObserver callback function, but because I'm using @Decorators  I don't prefer this solution

Comment: I figured it out. Before chrome 64 the ResizeObserver polyfill is used, but with the new Chrome, it uses the native implementation. I guess Zone.js should handle this, but because this is so new, Zone.js not yet supports this

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zone.js provide a patch for ResizeObserver >= chrome 64, it is not released, please wait for next version of zone.js (0.8.21) 
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/1012
here is a working sample.

https://github.com/JiaLiPassion/zone-resize-observer